# code igniter datamapper join get()

Tags: codeigniter, datamapper

I am using this join in my code igniter model

```
 $this->db->select('e.name, p.projects');
      $this->db->from('example as e');
      $this->db->join('procure as p', e.id = p.id');
      $this->db->where('e.cityid', '1');
      $this->db->where('e.status', '0');
```

I do not have separate table for join. Here is my data mapper, this is not giving any output.

I have two tables and I want to write a join query on them.I have this in my controller.

```
   $example = new Example();
      $example ->where_join_field('procure', FALSE);
```

**Update**

can you show me the snippet for joining three tables using data mapper.

Comment: @WanWizard:Can you help me out in this ?

Comment: Is there a question here? What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: @mcryan:How to convert my above ci query to data model ?

Comment: Please update your question to show the function, including definition and which file it is in and where you are trying to access it from.

Comment: @mcryan:See my update in question.

Comment: Try include join fields: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html#include_join_fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you don't do joins by hand with DMZ models (the sql generated will use joins nonetheless). The thing you are looking for is [Relations](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/relationtypes.html).

You have to set up your model's relations, using the `$has_one` and `$has_many` attributes, keeping the naming conventions, creating the necessary tables for many-to-many and so on. You can read about these in the docs [here](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/settingrelations.html) and [here](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/advancedrelations.html).

Once you got your models set up, you can use the `where_related` and `include_related` methods where you have used joins before:

1. **where_related** is for when you want to filter the models you are querying on some related model's field values. So if you have a related `project` set up on your `Example` class, you can write `->where_related('project', 'procure', false)`; and it will filter the returned `Example` instances based on their related project's procedure field. So basically it's the same conditionals that you would put into the `where` SQL clause.
2. **include_related** is for when you want to include fields from related models or even whole instance. So if you write `->include_related('project', 'projects')` when you query `Example` instances you will end up with a `project_projects` attribute on the returned instances. There are many options to control how these attributes should be created. Basically these are the fields you would have put into the `select` SQL clause.

There are magic methods created for every named relation and many other options, i refer you to the [Get (Advanced)](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html) page of the documentation for start and free to explore the [other](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/accessingrelations.html) [pages](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/joinfields.html) [describing](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/save.html#Relationship) [relations](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/delete.html#Relationship).

Comment: It will be immense pleasure if you provide on demo .zip file including database. I had do lots of try to use datamapper with joins. But not getting the exact single demo.

Comment: @Chintan7027: I've zipped a controller + few models with a sql schema and data together. I hope [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/71yn1vueof47rr5/so_15991597_demo.zip?dl=1) helps. You should be able to just drop it into a codeigniter project with datamapper already installed to it. It uses the array extension of datamapper DMZ so i've added a datamapper config too. Sorry for the late reply

Comment: Thank you so much @complex857; I have waiting for this